# using 'required' for 'select' tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

How can I use required with the below code of select. I had values for all options. As for required to work, default selected option should have empty value. How can I get the required working without removing value of any option? Is there some tweak ?

```
<select required>
<option value = "-1" selected> </option>
<option value = "1"> one </option>
<option value = "2"> two </option>
</select>
```

Comment: which validation library are you using?

Answer (score 2):

In most modern browsers, a form containing an element with `required` will not submit until it has a value.

To make `select` work like that use an empty string as the `value` for the default item:

```
<select required>
<option value = "" selected> </option>
<option value = "1"> one </option>
<option value = "2"> two </option>
</select>
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/zu80u9my/ (Form will not submit if a value has not been selected)

Comment: Not sure why but OP stated: `How can I get the required working without removing value of any option?`

Comment: Is there a way such that I had value for all options , and I can use required ?

Comment: @tarun14110 - no. `-1` is a value, so you'll need some custom validation and not rely on HTML5/browser default validation.